# Messaging app for compatible with iOS 6

Tags: gratis, android, ios, chat

I am looking for an messaging app which has support for both Android and iOS.

The app should

- be compatible with both Android and iOS
- support iOS 6
- be free

Up to date, most of the apps I looked at do not have iOS 6 support anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend [Telegaram](https://telegram.org/). I am currently using it on an old Android phone (4.1.2). It also runs on: iOS (6 and above), Android (2.2 and up) and Windows Phone. It also has desktop apps for Windows, OSX, and Linux.

See the FAQ page on the link for more information. To quote:

> Unlike WhatsApp, Telegram is a cloud-based messenger with seamless
>   sync. You can access your messages from several devices at once,
>   including tablets and computers, and share an unlimited number of
>   photos, videos and files (doc, zip, mp3, etc.) of up to 1,5 GB each.
>   And if you don't want to store that data on your device, you can
>   always keep it in the cloud.

It works using your phone number but you can also set up a username if you want. You can set account to "self-destruct" after a certain period.

It has the ability to have "secret chats" with a contact. To quote:

> Secret chats are meant for people who want more secrecy than the
>   average fella. All messages in secret chats use end-to-end encryption.
>   This means only you and the recipient can read those messages — nobody
>   else can decipher them, including us here at Telegram (more on this
>   here). Messages cannot be forwarded from secret chats. And when you
>   delete messages on your side of the conversation, the app on the other
>   side of the secret chat will be ordered to delete them as well.
>
> You can order your messages, photos, videos and files to self-destruct
>   in a set amount of time after they have been read or opened by the
>   recipient. The message will then disappear from both your and your
>   friend's devices.
>
> All secret chats in Telegram are device-specific and are not part of
>   the Telegram cloud. This means you can only access messages in a
>   secret chat from their device of origin. They are safe for as long as
>   your device is safe in your pocket.